# Filtering list items with ng-repeat from a selection/de-selection of a combination of checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter

I have a list of items which are frequently updated, based on changes to a price property. If the price of an item falls below a certain value (below 5) that item has a 'selected' property set to true and displayed in the results table (filtered on the selected property).

```
ng-repeat="item in dataPrices | filter: {selected:true}"
```

I want to add a series of checkboxes which, based on the selection/de-selection of a combination of checkboxes used should further filter the results - zero to three selections are possible

```
<label ng-click="productType('large')">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Large items</span>
</label>
<label ng-click="productType('small')">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Small items</span>
</label>
<label ng-click="productType('medium')">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Medium items</span>
</label>
```

I did try to add an additional filter to the ng-repeat

```
ng-repeat="item in dataPrices | filter: {selected:true} | filter: {size:'large'}"
```

which works, but I'm not sure how to add a combination of these based on the result of a combination of checkbox selection/de-selection. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

I have put this plunkr together which might make this a little clearer -  https://plnkr.co/edit/DHsOcWbfld7V7V1G8nIF?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You should apply custom `oRfilter` after built-in `filter : {selected: true}`:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {selected: true, size: 'large'},
      {selected: false, size: 'large'},
      {selected: false, size: 'medium'},
      {selected: true, size: 'medium'},
      {selected: true, size: 'small'}
    ];
    $scope.search = {};
}])
.filter('oRfilter', function(){
  return function(items, search){
    var out = [];    
    var atLeastOne = false;
    for(var prop in search)
      if(search[prop]){
        atLeastOne = true;
        out = out.concat(items.filter(function(x){ return x.size == prop; }));      
      }
    return atLeastOne ? out : items;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat='size in ["small", "medium", "large"]'>
    {{size}}: <input type='checkbox' ng-model='search[size]' />    
  </div>    
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='item in items | filter : {selected: true} | oRfilter : search'>{{item | json}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WgHQj4rbU3jgMMHNh81i?p=preview) does not work, because you have two **separated** controllers. You should connect them via events([updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rgraHXjKgddlaSIs7Ql5?p=preview)):

**navController:**

```
$scope.$watchCollection('search', function(arg){
    $scope.$parent.$broadcast('changed', arg);
});
```

**priceController:**

```
$scope.search = {};
$scope.$on('changed', function(event, arg){
    $scope.search = arg;
})
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Conceptually I _think_ it's close, but It doesn't seem to work when i adapted my code with yours - see the updated plunkr , https://plnkr.co/edit/WgHQj4rbU3jgMMHNh81i?p=preview

Comment: Thanks so much. Personally I feel i have learnt a lot from this! Thanks again : )

Answer (score 0):

If you use a lot of additional filters, it ins't work, because every filter is applied on the result of the previous filter. 
So when if you select 'large' and 'small' when you do this: {size:'large'}, the result doesn't contain the 'small' itens to apply another filter.

I think you can do this in two ways.

1 - You can return a function to your ng-repeat, that returns the filtered list:

```
 ng-repeat="item in filtered()"
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.filtered = function() {
  //take the selected filter and your data and apply the filters
  //return the filtered list
  // you can code this with lodash
  // $scope.data -> your data
  // $scope.productType ->  can be one or multiple
  var filtered = _.filter($scope.data, function(item) {
      //Note that this filter is just an example, this implementation depends on what you really need and how your filter selection works.
      return item.selected && item.size === $scope.productType;
  });
  return filtered;
}
```

In this situation you need to write your own filter and apply to the list. A library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) should help you a lot.

You could apply another filter in ng-repeat too:

```
ng-repeat="item in filtered() | anotherFilter"
```

2 - You can control manually your filter flow. This is a lite bit complex because you need to know exactly how your view should work and when you need to update your view. You will have performance improvements with this approach.

Basically you will use another list to receive your filtered data:

```
ng-repeat="item in filteredList"
```

And when you need to call a function (manually) to update this list. So

```
$scope.filteredList = getFilteredData();
function getFilteredData() {
  return _.filter($scope.data, function(item) {
      return item.selected && item.size === $scope.productType;
  });
}
```

Note that in this approach you need to call `$scope.filteredList = getFilteredData();` every time that you want to update your view. So every time that you select a new size filter or something like that, you need to execute the code.